# grep matching specific position in lines using words from other file

Tags: shell, unix, grep

I have 2 file

file1:

```
12342015010198765hello
12342015010188765hello
12342015010178765hello
```

whose each line contains fields at fixed positions, for example, position `13 - 17` is for `account_id`

file2:

```
98765
88765
```

which contains a list of `account_id`s.

In Korn Shell, **I want to print lines from file1 whose position `13 - 17` match one of `account_id` in file2.**

I can't do

```
grep -f file2 file1
```

because `account_id` in file2 can match other fields at other positions.

I have tried using pattern in file2:

```
^.{12}98765.*
```

but did not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Using awk

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=1;next;} substr($0,13,5) in a' file2 file1
12342015010198765hello
12342015010188765hello
```

#### How it works

- `NR==FNR{a[$1]=1;next;}`

  FNR is the number of lines read so far from the current file and NR is the total number of lines read so far.  Thus, if `FNR==NR`, we are reading the first file which is `file2`.

  Each ID in in file2 is saved in array `a`.  Then, we skip the rest of the commands and jump to the `next` line.
- `substr($0,13,5) in a`

  If we reach this command, we are working on the second file, `file1`.

  This condition is true if the 5 character long substring that starts at position 13 is in array `a`.  If the condition is true, then awk performs the default action which is to print the line.

### Using grep

You mentioned trying

```
grep '^.{12}98765.*' file2
```

That uses extended regex syntax which means that `-E` is required.  Also, there is no value in matching `.*` at the end: it will always match.  Thus, try:

```
$ grep -E '^.{12}98765' file1
12342015010198765hello
```

To get both lines:

```
$ grep -E '^.{12}[89]8765' file1
12342015010198765hello
12342015010188765hello
```

This works because `[89]8765` just happens to match the IDs of interest in file2.  The awk solution, of course, provides more flexibility in what IDs to match.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed` with extended regex:

```
sed -r 's@.*@/^.{12}&/p@' file2 |sed -nr -f- file1
```

Using Basic regex:

```
sed 's@.*@/^.\\{12\\}&/p@' file1 |sed -n -f- file
```

Explanation:

```
sed -r 's@.*@/^.{12}&/p@' file2
```

will generate an output:

```
/.{12}98765/p
/.{12}88765/p
```

which is then used as a `sed` script for the next `sed` after pipe, which outputs:

```
12342015010198765hello
12342015010188765hello
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using Grep**

The most convenient is to put each alternative in a separate line of the file.

You can look at this question:

[grep multiple patterns single file argument list too long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31479822/grep-multiple-patterns-single-file-argument-list-too-long#autocomment111933843)