# Filter file with a list from another file, based on substring

Tags: shell, unix, filter

`file1.txt`:

```
1234567890IDNUMBER1
1234567890IDNUMBER2
1234567890IDNUMBER3
1234567890IDNUMBER4
1234567890IDNUMBER5
```

Note: IDNUMBERX is a fixed lenght unique ID. In this particular case it is 9 characters long and it start ALWAYS at position 11.

`file2.txt`:

```
IDNUMBER1
IDNUMBER2
IDNUMBER4
```

Note: List of IDs.

What I want to do is filter first file to delete all lines with IDs not listed in 2nd file.

Expected output:

```
1234567890IDNUMBER1
1234567890IDNUMBER2
1234567890IDNUMBER4
```

I found VERY similar question here:
[grep matching specific position in lines using words from other file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31332512/grep-matching-specific-position-in-lines-using-words-from-other-file)

I tried marked answer there and it is not working for me like author describe:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]=1;next;} substr($0,11,9) in a' file2.txt file1.txt
```

returns me just one line (last matching):

```
1234567890IDNUMBER4
```

the same for the data from linked question.

What can be wrong?

Using: GNU Awk 4.1.4, API: 1.1 (GNU MPFR 3.1.5-p2, GNU MP 6.1.2)

**EDIT**

Stupid me... It was all about line ending on windows... Windows carriage return sign was causing the problem.

I used:

```
awk '{ sub("\r$", ""); print }' dos.txt > unix.txt
```

to convert file to remove carriage return. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2613817/3804906)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[substr($0,11)]=$0;next} ($1 in a){print a[$1]}' File1.txt File2.txt
1234567890IDNUMBER1
1234567890IDNUMBER2
1234567890IDNUMBER4
```

EDIT: Adding one more solution on same too now.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$2]=$0;next} ($1 in a){print a[$1]}' FIELDWIDTHS="10 9"  File1.txt File2.txt
```

Comment: now it returns `1234567890IDNUMBER1
1234567890IDNUMBER2` so number4 is missing

Comment: @ilovkatie: That worked for me successfully, you could also check my edit command too. Which uses FIELDWIDTHS facility provided by gawk.

Comment: Also, I added output of my first command, which looks correct only, let me know on same. Also make sure you are NOT having any carriage characters in your Input_files.

Comment: ye! this is a problem. AWK command I have posted is returning last id match because last line doesn't have `CR LF` at the end of the line. So, is it only windows related problem? (don't have access to linux right now to check)